# Change max_input_var limit from direct admin

Tags: laravel, directadmin

I want to try to change the max_input_vars limit from direct admin
I have also change the max_input_vars limit from php settings

[image]

But when I print the value of max_input_var from controller they have return 1000.

[image]

[image]

Anybody can describe what can I do?

Comment: You need to show the code that is saving the `max_input_vars`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this; `ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);`

Comment: I also try in .htaccess file of laravel this line of code :
    php_value max_input_vars 10000
but they can't

Comment: And I try this ini_set() function but the value is not change